# How can I append dynamic input fields when the page loads?

Tags: php, html, jquery

I have tried in this strategy->

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    var countPos=0;
    var add_button=$('#add_position');
    var wrapper=$('#position_fields');
    window.console && console.log('Document ready called');
   //When the user clicks on the add button then It inserts these input fields
    $(add_button).click(function(event){
        // http://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/
        event.preventDefault();
        if ( countPos >=9 ) {
            alert("Maximum of nine position entries exceeded");
            return;
        }
        countPos++;
        window.console && console.log("Adding position "+countPos);
        $(wrapper).append(
            '<div id="position'+countPos+'"> \
        <p>Year: <input type="text" name="year'+countPos+'" value="" /> \
        <input type="button" value="-" \
            onclick="$(\'#position'+countPos+'\').remove();return false;"></p> \
        <textarea name="desc'+countPos+'" rows="8" cols="80"></textarea>\
        </div>');
    });

});
```

Here is my html segment->

```
<div class="container">
<h1>Ashiful Islam Prince's Resume Registry</h1>


<h1>Editing Profile for UMSI</h1>
<?php
if(isset($_SESSION['profile_error'])) {
$error = $_SESSION['profile_error'];
 unset($_SESSION["profile_error"]);


 echo '<span class="text-danger">';


   echo $error;


   echo '</span>';
}
?>
<form method="post">
<p>First Name:
    <input type="text" name="first_name" value="<?php
    echo $firstName;
    ?>"
      ></p><br>

<p>Last Name:
    <input type="text" name="last_name" value="<?php
    echo $lastName;
    ?>"</p>

<p>Email:
    <input type="text" name="email" value="<?php
    echo $Email;
    ?>"</p><br>
<span class="text-danger">
    <?php
    if(isset($email_sign_error))
        echo $email_sign_error;

    ?>
</span>


<p>Headline:<br/>
    <input type="text" name="headline" value="<?php
    echo $Headline;
    ?>"</p>


<p>Summary:<br/>
    <textarea name="summary" rows="8" cols="80">
        <?php
        echo $Summary;

        ?>
    </textarea>
<p>Position : <input type="submit"  class="add_position" id="add_position" 
name="addPosition" value="+">

<div class="position_fields" id="position_fields">

</div>


<p>
    <input type="submit" value="Save" name="btn" class="btn btn-primary">
    <input type="submit" name="cancel" value="Cancel">
</p>
</form>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

The problem I have faced: In this above program I can display the input fields when the user clicks on the add button. But I want to display these fields when the page loads mean without clicking on the add button I want to print those fields. How can I go to my destination?

Here is my php code for fetching data from the database:

```
<?php
try{
//Need to make a connection
$con=new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=courseraassignment","root","");


$statement=$con->prepare("select * from position 
                   where profile_id=:profile_id");
$statement->execute(array(
    ':profile_id'=>$_REQUEST['profile_id']
));
foreach($statement as $row){
   echo $row['year'];
   echo $row['description'];
   echo "<br>";
}
}catch(PDOException $e){
echo "error".$e->getMessage();
}
 ?>
```

From this code I am fetching year and description from the position table and want to show these value to these input fields when the page loads.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222111/discussion-on-question-by-ashiful-islam-prince-how-can-i-append-dynamic-input-fi).

Comment: Ok, I am trying to maintain this guideline from today.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

below code creating field when page loads and when user click add button try this if there are any error let me know

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    var countPos=0;
    var add_button=$('#add_position');
    var wrapper=$('#position_fields');
    window.console && console.log('Document ready called');
   //When the user clicks on the add button then It inserts these input fields
    function addField(event){
       event.preventDefault();
        if ( countPos >=9 ) {
            alert("Maximum of nine position entries exceeded");
            return;
        }
        countPos++;
        window.console && console.log("Adding position "+countPos);
        $(wrapper).append(
            '<div id="position'+countPos+'"> \
        <p>Year: <input type="text" name="year'+countPos+'" value="" /> \
        <input type="button" value="-" \
            onclick="$(\'#position'+countPos+'\').remove();return false;"></p> \
        <textarea name="desc'+countPos+'" rows="8" cols="80"></textarea>\
        </div>');
    }
    $(add_button).click(function(event){
        addField();
    });

    addField();

});
```

and html will be like this

```
<div class="container">
<h1>Ashiful Islam Prince's Resume Registry</h1>


<h1>Editing Profile for UMSI</h1>
<?php
if(isset($_SESSION['profile_error'])) {
$error = $_SESSION['profile_error'];
 unset($_SESSION["profile_error"]);


 echo '<span class="text-danger">';


   echo $error;


   echo '</span>';
}
?>
<form method="post">
<p>First Name:
    <input type="text" name="first_name" value="<?php
    echo $firstName;
    ?>"
      ></p><br>

<p>Last Name:
    <input type="text" name="last_name" value="<?php
    echo $lastName;
    ?>"</p>

<p>Email:
    <input type="text" name="email" value="<?php
    echo $Email;
    ?>"</p><br>
<span class="text-danger">
    <?php
    if(isset($email_sign_error))
        echo $email_sign_error;

    ?>
</span>


<p>Headline:<br/>
    <input type="text" name="headline" value="<?php
    echo $Headline;
    ?>"</p>


<p>Summary:<br/>
    <textarea name="summary" rows="8" cols="80">
        <?php
        echo $Summary;

        ?>
    </textarea>
<p>Position : <input type="button"  class="add_position" id="add_position" 
name="addPosition" value="+">

<div class="position_fields" id="position_fields">
     <?php foreach($your_data as $count => $data){ ?>
           <div id="position'+count+'">
               <p>Year: <input type="text" name="year'+count+'" value="" />
                 <input type="button" value="-" onclick="$(\'#position'+count+'\').remove();return false;"></p>
                   <textarea name="desc'+count+'" rows="8" cols="80"></textarea>
           </div>
        <?php } ?>
</div>


<p>
    <input type="submit" value="Save" name="btn" class="btn btn-primary">
    <input type="submit" name="cancel" value="Cancel">
</p>
</form>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```